# How to install libsnmp on CentOS 6.5?

Tags: linux, centos, package-management, yum

I'm trying to use software on my server that requires `libsnmp`. I tried running:

```
 yum list libsnmp
```

But it says:

```
Error: No matching Packages to list
```

I also tried:

```
yum search libsnmp
```

But it doesn't return any results, either.

How can I install libsnmp on CentOS 6.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
yum -y install net-snmp net-snmp-utils net-snmp-libs
```